# Error con consulta sumar campos de diferentes tablas en MySql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Lo que busco es que me sume la cantidad total de cada campo y me la muestre pero lo que me muestra es un texto, no entiendo por qué pasa esto

CODIGO:

```
SELECT totales_bonos.idEmpleado, 'bonos.pmonto'  Bonos,
                                 'anticipos.primerMonto'  Anticipos,
                                 'deducciones.primerMonto'  Deducciones
FROM
    (SELECT idEmpleado,
           SUM(b.pmonto)  'bonos.pmonto'
    FROM bonos b
    GROUP BY idEmpleado) as totales_bonos

    INNER JOIN

    (SELECT idEmpleado,
           SUM(a.primerMonto) 'anticipos.primerMonto'
    FROM anticipos a
    GROUP BY idEmpleado) as totales_anticipos

    on (totales_bonos.idEmpleado = totales_anticipos.idEmpleado)

    INNER JOIN

    (SELECT idEmpleado,
           SUM(d.primerMonto) 'deducciones.primerMonto'
    FROM deducciones d
    GROUP BY idEmpleado) as totales_deducciones

    on (totales_bonos.idEmpleado = totales_deducciones.idEmpleado)

ORDER BY totales_bonos.idEmpleado
```

ESTO ES LO QUE ME SALE:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Stivin. Para mejorar tu pregunta has de añadir los problemas que tienes. Qué errores te produce? puedes poner ejemplos de datos y resultado esperado? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, quita todas las comillas simples de tu consulta, las comillas simples sirven para cadenas, no para asignar alias

Comment: Si las quito me da un error y me dice lo siguiente:
#1054 - La columna 'bonos.pmonto' en field list es desconocida

Comment: en lugar de usar subconsultas en el from usa consultas anidadas en el select, así te saldra

Comment: Voy a probar con eso, aunque no se como hacer select anidados, gracias por responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas cometiendo enormes errores en esa consulta, para hacerla te recomiendo utilizar consultas anidadas de esta forma:

```
SELECT T.idEmpleado,
    (SELECT SUM(b.pmonto)  
    FROM bonos b
    where b.idEmpleado=T.idEmpleado) as Bonos,
    (SELECT SUM(a.primerMonto)
    FROM anticipos a
    where a.idEmpleado=T.idEmpleado) as Anticipos,
    (SELECT SUM(d.primerMonto) 
    FROM deducciones d
    where d.idEmpleado=T.idEmpleado) as Deducciones
FROM totales_bonos T
ORDER BY T.idEmpleado
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: muchas Gracias me ayudó bastante