# Mostrar registros agrupados por mes en una consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo todo el sistema creado, solo me faltan los reportes, la tabla principal es `averias` la cual tiene como atributos `campo`, `fecha` y otros irrelevantes, el SQL que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
SELECT centro, MONTH(fecha) as mes, COUNT(*) as Total FROM averias WHERE 
fecha BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' GROUP BY centro, mes
```

esto me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
centro | mes | Total
---------------------
2003   |5    |1 
2005   |5    |2 
2019   |5    |1 
2020   |5    |2 
2026   |5    |1 
2030   |5    |1 
2055   |5    |1 
2188   |5    |1
```

Mi problema se produce al llevar esto a un reporte en el view para hacer el recuento de averías por mes, no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Necesito que el reporte quede de la siguiente forma:

```
Centro  Ene Feb Mar Abr May Jun Jul Ago Sep Oct Nov Dic 
2035     1   5   6   2   3   4   2   2   2   3   4   5  
2038     4   5   4   2   3   4   2   1   2   3   4   5
```

y después poderlo visualizar en mi Sistema que esta en Codeigniter.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, podrías hacerlo con consultas anidadas, puedes tomar como base esta pregunta: [Error con consulta sumar campos de diferentes tablas en MySql
](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158646/77879), inténtalo y si se te complica puedo echarte una mano

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo reviso y te digo. Saludos

Comment: de nada @elyera, utiliza `@the-breaker` si necesitas algo

Comment: @the-breaker no le encuentro el resultado, te pongo lo que puse: SELECT centro,
    (SELECT MONTH(fecha)
    FROM averias
    WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31') as Mes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM averias ) as Total
FROM averias
GROUP BY centro, mes                y no me da nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer la consulta puedes anidar los meses de la siguiente manera:

```
select V.campo, (
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as ene,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as feb,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as mar,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as abr,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as may,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as jun,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as jul,(
    select count(*)
    from visita A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as ago,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as sep,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as oct,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as nov,(
    select count(*)
    from averias A 
    where A.fecha BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31' and A.campo=V.campo
) as dic
from (select DISTINCT campo
from averias) V
```

Puede parecer extenso pero solo es como si hicieras las consultas por mes y las unieras en una sola, de esa forma puedes mostrar los registros por mes e imagino que cambiaras el año con php.

Otra solución es utilizar `case` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT averias.centro, 
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ene,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abr,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ago,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep, 
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(averias.fecha) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dic
FROM averias
WHERE averias.fecha BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY averias.centro
```

Espero que sirva a los que lo necesiten. Saludos.

Comment: @elyera, moralmente no podría aceptar el crédito por una respuesta que no es mía, pero si es tu decisión, bueno, lo importante es que sea de utilidad...

Comment: Si realmente y lo importante es que le sirva a otros, yo he solucionado muchos problemas que he tenido con solo entrar a este sitio y ver respuestas. Gracias por el aporte.