# Consulta Mysql Select multiple

Tags: mysql-workbench

Qué tal, tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es una tabla como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dónde me muestre la cantidad de alumnos por semestre que hay en cada carrera, en mi tabla Historial, existen más de un alumno con la misma id debido a que esa tabla se refiere a las materias y como cada alumno tiene varias materias y cada materia pertenece a un semestre:

tengo la siguiente consulta que me da el semestre más alto del alumno, que éste es mi semestre que quiero consultar:

```
SELECT idAlum, MAX(semes) as Semestre FROM Historial
GROUP BY idAlum;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo esta otra consulta que me da el semestre más alto por carrera, pero está mal debido a que si tengo 2 alumnos de la misma carrera solo toma en cuenta al más alto.

```
SELECT idPro, MAX(Semes) as Semestre FROM Historial
GROUP BY idPro;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que tengo que realizar un select dentro de otro select pero no he podido resolver esa parte.

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacerlo con consultas anidadas, aquí hay una pregunta que puedes usar de base:  [Mostrar registros agrupados por mes en una consulta MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168660)

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando subconsultas se puede llegar al objetivo. Para cada columna se estaría creando una subconsulta que recupere las cantidades por cada semestre. Dependiendo de los semestres que pueda tener debes ir agregando los "sub-bloques".

```
SELECT carreras.idPro as carrera, 
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '1er Semestre'
) as 1erSemestre,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '2do Semestre'
) as 2doSemestre,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '3er Semestre'
) as 3erSemestre,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '4to Semestre'
) as 4toSemestre,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '5to Semestre'
) as 5toSemestre,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '6to Semestre'
) as 6toSemestre,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '8vo Semestre'
) as 8voSemestre,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM Historial
    WHERE Historial.idPro = carreras.idPro
    AND Semes = '9no Semestre'
) as 9voSemestre
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT idPro FROM Historial
) as carreras
```

Comment: Qué tal, intente usar ese código, pero tiene un conflicto, en mi tabla historial existen registros del mismo alumno más de 2 o 10 veces, en cada registro tiene un diferente semestre debido a la materia. 
Lo que intento hacer es contar solo el semestre más alto por alumno por carrera.